# what is the best way to read single line files in Java

Tags: java

Is it necessary to create buffered reader while loop and all to read single line file? its also constant never changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
String txt = new Scanner(new File(path)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

This will read an entire file into the String.

Let me break that down for you:

```
String txt = // the resulting String is stored here
new Scanner( // Create a scanner to read the file
new File( "pathToFile" ) ) // pass a new file to the scanner to read
.useDelimiter("\\Z") // set the delimiter to the end of the file
.next(); // read the scanner until the next delimiter, 
         // in this case it is the end of the file.
```

Comment: Ummm ... this reads a multi-line file as a single line.  That's not what the question asked ...

Comment: @Stephen, It reads an entire file like he wants.  He just mentioned that his file was one line.  But it really doesn't matter.

Comment: *"... like he wants"* - but NOT like he asked for.  The problem is with his question.  He needs to read an entire file, but asked if he could avoid using a buffered reader when reading a single line file.  We only know what what he **actually** wanted because of his comments above.

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) makes it easier to read files. Also remember [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Comment: @Esko Luontola I need to read this file(containing single string) to string thats it

Comment: Another recommendation for `Scanner`. I've been using it for my File I/O since it became available.

Comment: @London: `String myLine = myScanner.nextLine();` For a more complicated file, you'd want to use `hasNextLine()` in a while loop, but for your specifications, a single call to `nextLine()` should be fine.

Comment: @Brian S thank you for your response when I use that String myLine = myScanner.nextLine(); , then myLine equals name of the file, in my case Scanner scan = new Scanner("HEADER"); it outputs HEADER

Comment: You're using the wrong constructor for Scanner - try `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("HEADER"));`

Comment: @London: As barrowc says, make sure you're creating a `Scanner` which scans a `File`. `Scanner` is also capable of scanning `String` and streams as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about correct character conversion you could use InputStream, rather than using the Reader classes:

A performance discussion:

http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly

Answer (score 0):

> As the title itself says, is it necessary to create buffered reader while loop and all to read single line file? its also constant never changes

No it is not absolutely necessary, if the file is **really** *always* a single line and *never* changes.

1. If the file is really always a single line, you could just read the first line; i.e. no need to loop.
2. If the file really never changes, you may not even need to read it; i.e. you could embed the single line contents in the program itself.

However, in reality, both of your assumptions are probably false.  There is always the *possibility* that the file might contain more lines (or be empty) or that it might contain something different to what you expect.  At the very least, it would be a good idea if your program at least *checked* that its assumptions were not invalid.  For example:

```
BufferedReader br = ...

// Read contents of a 1 line file.
String line = br.readLine();
if (line == null || line.length() == 0) {
    System.out.println("where's my input?");
} else if (br.readLine() != null) {
    System.out.println("too much input!");
} else {
    ...
}
```

In addition, as others have mentioned, there other ways of reading / parsing input that may work better than simply using a `BufferedReader`.  It depends on what you are doing with the line you are reading from the file.

**EDIT**

> Is there something in java like include in php?

Not in the core libraries.  But IIRC there is an Apache commons utility class called [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) that has various methods for doing this kind of thing.  For example, there are methods that read an entire file as a byte array or string, and another that reads the file and returns the lines as an array of strings.

(But hey, why would you add a 3rd-party dependency for something as trivial as this?  It is only half a dozen lines of Java code to do the job properly yourself!!)

Comment: I like the second point you made, I don't think my assumption is false because this is HEADER file, I need to just include it, it might change, but I will have to change it manually its not appended at any time. Is there something in java like include in php?

Comment: @London - you are contradicting yourself.  First sentence you say that your assumption is true; i.e. that the file never changes.  Next sentence you say that you might change the file manually.  In reality, your assumption is false AND unnecessary.

Comment: alright it's late here that might be the case tnx for the info about your above, I'm not being sarcastic